# PHP array_diif() not working for SQL output arrays

Tags: php, arrays, array-difference

I have this php script that retrieve records from a SQL database.

```
$sql1 = "SELECT TOP 3 id,hipoName FROM t2o_hipo_list"; 
$sql2 = "SELECT TOP 3 id,hipoName FROM hipo_list";

$result1 = sqlsrv_query($conn,$sql1);
$result2 = sqlsrv_query($conn,$sql2);

$row1=[];
$row2=[];

while ($rs1 = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result1, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {

    $row1[] = $rs1;
}

while ($rs2 = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result2, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {

    $row2[] = $rs2;
}

print_r($row1);
print_r($row2);
```

The output of the above script was,

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 
            [hipoName] => Channa 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 
            [hipoName] => Chaminda 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 
            [hipoName] => Niroshana 
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2531
            [hipoName] => Chaminda 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2532
            [hipoName] => Niroshana 
        )

)
```

Then, I used the array difference on the `$row1` and `$row2` variables, as mentioned below,

```
$x = array_diff($row1,$row2);
```

However, an error generated saying,

> Error: Array to string conversion

I tried the same concept with a simple script as shown below,

```
<?php

    $active = ['a','b','c','d','e'];
    $current = ['b','c','f','g'];

    echo 'data 1: '; 
    print_r($active);
    echo '<br/>';
    echo 'data 2: '; 
    print_r($current);

    echo '<br/><br/>';

    $a1 = array_diff($active,$current);
    $a2 = array_diff($current,$active);

    echo 'output 1: '; 
    print_r($a1);
    echo '<br/>';
    echo 'outut 2: '; 
    print_r($a2);

?>
```

And the output for the above script is what I need,

```
data 1: Array ( [0] => a [1] => b [2] => c [3] => d [4] => e ) 
data 2: Array ( [0] => b [1] => c [2] => f [3] => g ) 

output 1: Array ( [0] => a [3] => d [4] => e ) 
outut 2: Array ( [2] => f [3] => g )
```

How can I achieve this output, is it possible to get it in this same concept?.

Comment: don't spam tags, this is not a `mysql` problem, u should only tag relevant tags

Comment: Try like **$x = array_diff($row1[0],$row1[1],$row1[2],$row2[0],$row2[1]);**

Answer (score 0):

As the [manual for array_diff()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php#refsect1-function.array-diff-notes) states:

> **Note:** Two elements are considered equal if and only if *(string) $elem1 === (string) $elem2*. In other words: when the string representation is the same.
>
> **Note:** This function only checks one dimension of a n-dimensional array. Of course you can check deeper dimensions by using *array_diff($array1[0], $array2[0]);*.

So it is completely natural that you get an *Array to string conversion* error for multi-dimensional arrays.

To achieve the desired result, you should use [array_udiff()](https://secure.php.net/array_udiff) with your own, custom comparison function:

```
$active  = ['a','b','c','d','e'];
$current = ['b','c','f','g'];

$compare = function($a, $b) {
    // The spaceship operator was introduced in PHP 7
    return $a <=> $b;
};

// Returns: [0 => "a", 3 => "d", 4 => "e"];
$a1 = array_udiff($active, $current, $compare);

// This works on all current PHP versions
$compare = function($a, $b) {
    if ($a === $b) {
        return 0;
    }

    return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;
};

// Returns: [2 => "f", 3 => "g"];
$a2 = array_udiff($current, $active, $compare);
```